# Failure to save emoji by sql in mybatis mapper

Tags: mysql, mybatis, emoji

mysql version: 5.7.20

mysql-connector-java: 5.1.37

encoding: utf-8 unicode(utf8mb4)

sql in mapper:

```
    <insert id="insert" parameterType="cc.xx.xx.entity.PersonInfo" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id" >
    insert into person_info ( name, age)
    values (
        #{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{age,jdbcType=INTEGER}
    )
</insert>
```

question:

save data to mysql failure when name contain emoji, but removed jdbcType  try  agin, it save successfully.

name like this: 
 "namename"

exception:

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x90\xB6\xF0\x9F...' for column 'objectDescription' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:959) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3870) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3806) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2470) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2617) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2550) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1192) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.preparedStatement_execute(FilterChainImpl.java:3051) ~[druid-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterEventAdapter.preparedStatement_execute(FilterEventAdapter.java:440) ~[druid-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.preparedStatement_execute(FilterChainImpl.java:3049) ~[druid-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
    at com.alibaba.druid.wall.WallFilter.preparedStatement_execute(WallFilter.java:619) ~[druid-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.preparedStatement_execute(FilterChainImpl.java:3049) ~[druid-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterEventAdapter.preparedStatement_execute(FilterEventAdapter.java:440) ~[druid-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.preparedStatement_execute(FilterChainImpl.java:3049) ~[druid-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
    at com.alibaba.druid.proxy.jdbc.PreparedStatementProxyImpl.execute(PreparedStatementProxyImpl.java:167) ~[druid-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledPreparedStatement.execute(DruidPooledPreparedStatement.java:498) ~[druid-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:46) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:74) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:50) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.update(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:198) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:185) ~[mybatis-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor220.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_112]`

Comment: So you fixed the problem, what it the question?

Comment: I do not know why removed 'jdbcType' can be save success.

Comment: In this case your question is incomplete. It lacks the error message that you get and the parameter that you pass to the query.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply，I have added parameter and exception message.

Answer (score 3):

The *table* needs to be specified `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

The connection needs to be specified `ut8mb4`.  I don't know MyBatis, but something like this is needed for JDBC:

> Add `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` to the JDBC URL (or maybe it is =true and =utf8)